# Existence of intertwiner between adjoint representation and arbitrary representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\rho\in\operatorname{Hom}\left(G,\operatorname{Aut}(V)\right)$ be an orthogonal representation of a compact Lie group $G$ on the real vector space $V$ and $\operatorname{Ad}\in\operatorname{Hom}\left(G,\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})\right)$ the adjoint representation. Under which conditions on $G$ and/or $V$ there exists a non-trivial intertwiner between $\rho$ and $\operatorname{Ad}$, i.e. a $T\colon{V}\to\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\operatorname{Ad}(g)\circ{T}=T\circ\rho(g),\forall{g}\in{G}$ ? If there are such conditions, is there a way to explicitly construct $T$ and, if yes, how?

If this question is too difficult or impossible to be answered for interwiners between $\rho$ and $\operatorname{Ad}$, then what about at the Lie algebra level? That is, under which conditions there exists a non-trivial $L\colon{V}\to\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\operatorname{ad}(X)\circ{L}=L\circ\rho_*(X),\forall{X}\in\mathfrak{g}$ and, if this set of conditions is not empty, is there a way to explicitly construct such an $L$?

Comment: Do you mean to require $T$ to be nonzero?  Otherwise you can always just take $T=0$...

Comment: yes, of course.